# Factoring $2{^{3^{k+1}}}+1$

Tags: induction, factoring

I'm trying to factor $2{^{3^{k+1}}}+1=(X+1)(Y-2^{3^{k}}+1)$ and I don't know how to split the $2{^{3^{k+1}}}$ term into $X$ and $Y$. What is the trick here so that I can recognize this type of thing with other problems? This is for an induction problem I'm working on. The problem is to show that $n|(2^n+1)$ where $n$ is a power of $3$. Any hints or different approaches are welcome.

Comment: Hint: $2^{3^{k+1}}  + 1 = (2^{3^k})^3 + 1^3$.

Comment: @player3236 I don't know why, but I am struggling with this. This problem has showed my weakness with the power to a power law. I'm thinking of letting $X=2^{3^{k}}$, but then wouldn't $Y$ have to equal $2^3$? That doesn't work.

Comment: We have the factorization $a^3 + b^3 = (a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$.